# How can i get data from a specific user rather then ID in my django app

Tags: python, django

i am trying to get date from a user when sending a webhook. The JSON will be handling the username of which user i want the data to be used from . but i get an error that user is expecting an id how can i make it that it is looking for a username rather then id.[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIFnc.png)

and this is my Models code

```
    class Bybitapidatas(models.Model):
        #user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,default=1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        apikey = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        apisecret = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    
        
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.user) + self.apikey + self.apisecret
```

and this is my views file where i am trying to get the data for the user

```
@csrf_exempt
@require_POST
def webhook(request):
    #get current users keys        
    jsondata = request.body
    data = json.loads(jsondata)
    for the_data in data: 
      users = the_data
      print(users)
    

    database = Bybitapidatas.objects.get(user=users)# this is where it is asking for the id?
    for apikey in database:
        apikey = apikey.apikey
    for apisecret in database:
        apisecret = apisecret.apisecret

    session = HTTP(endpoint='https://api-testnet.bybit.com/', api_key=apikey, api_secret=apisecret,spot=True)
    print(session.place_active_order(
        symbol="BTCUSDT",
        side="Buy",
        type="MARKET",
        qty="20",
        timeInForce="GTC"
    ))
    print(apikey)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `__` to follow the user relationship in your query to filter by the username field of the related user

```
database = Bybitapidatas.objects.get(user__username=users)
```

`Bybitapidatas.user` is not unique, this query may return multiple results in which case you will get an error.